# Can we assume that /wp-json/ will always be /wp-json/ under any circumstances when creating custom REST routes?

Tags: rest-api

For more context:

[WP REST API Is it rather easy to rename the default wp-json uri part?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247862/wp-rest-api-is-it-rather-easy-to-rename-the-default-wp-json-uri-part)

It seems that it's rather easy to change `wp-json` to anything.

---

I'm passing this link to my custom route to the JS file through localization:

```
$params = [
    'rest_link' => esc_url( get_site_url() . '/wp-json/block_help/v1/block_identification?block_identifier=' )
];
wp_localize_script( $handle, 'block_help_data', $params );
```

But I wonder, is it correct to also add the `/wp-json/` to the hard-coded link as well? Most likely not, but if so -

Isn't there any `get_json_prefix` function that I can use to retrieve whatever the new prefix is?

Answer (score 3):

Sure they can!

Actually the structure you used is assuming that url rewrites are on. Which may be or may be not.

To assure the right endpoint, you must use `get_rest_url` function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/

So in your case, this would be:

```
'get_rest_url' => get_rest_url(null, '/block_help/v1/block_identi...')
```